# How to manually query a cache table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have the following query:

```
select 1
```

If I run the query again it will grab it from cache:

> Query complete (0.1 sec elapsed, cached)

However, if I run a query like:

```
SELECT 1
```

It will not grab it from cache. Is there a way to manually query the cache table? For example, converting `SELECT 1` into the query `SELECT * FROM name_of_cache_table`?

Query normalization works in the above case, but for our purposes we're looking to be able to directly access cache as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to query the cached table since it creates an anonymous table. See [How cached results are stored](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#how_cached_results_are_stored) for more details.

To be able to see these anonymous tables, you need to invoke `bq ls -a` in your terminal since it is not possible to view them in the BQ UI. See [listing datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/listing-datasets#listing_datasets_in_a_project).

But take note that querying from cached tables is discouraged since they expire within 24 hours.

I tried this in my project and I got a few anonymous tables (I changed some values of the given test tables just so they are not 100% same with mine).

**Command:**

```
bq ls -a --project_id my-project
```

The anonymous tables starts with underscore then random string values:

```
_04c819c1520b1c756fc2a6364v87c5fc9d53f48c
_18af1144380d70b33cc27c9975c444fdfe36dfa9
_730f58d68c6f40ed0335322e46c4c87cer3af6290
....
```

To check if the data you need is on these datasets, you can check the __TABLES__ and it will return fields like `creation_time` and `last_modified_time`.

**Check Table metadata:**

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM
 `_730f58d68c6f40ed0335322e46c4c87cer3af6290.__TABLES__`
```

**Metadata result:**

[image]

**Try querying one of these tables:**

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM
 `_730f58d68c6f40ed0335322e46c4c87cer3af6290.anon36335c2bcd73b61558b7028ca8666efac3802a28`
```

**Result from anonymous table:**

[image]